# Username/password login for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, forms-authentication

Is it possible to configure MOSS 2007 to display an HTML-based username/password from to unauthenticated users, instead of using digest authentication (which displays a basic authentication like popup in the browser).

Outlook Web Access has this option built in.

Is the same possible for MOSS 2007?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this Microsoft article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975136(v=office.12).aspx#MOSS2007FBAPart1_BasicSetup

This will give you a step by step guide on adding FBA (Forms Based Authentication) to a sharepoint site.

I hope this helps...

Comment: There's no way of doing that without setting up a new membership database? I would like to keep the current membership/user store and just do the authentication part directly using an HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

you need to turn on forms authentication in central admin for your web application